# Adding header and footer to SQL Output

Tags: sql, header, output

I would like to automate some code for file output which would include header and footer in the output and prevent me from having to manually open the output file and add myself. The code is fairly simple:

```
Select Customer#, EmailAddress

from dbo.customertable
```

But I need to add a Header:

```
HYYYYMMDD
```

And a Footer with Record Count and leading zeros:

```
T00004000
```

Any assistance as to how to do this within the code and not have to manually add later?

Thanks!
Phil

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server:

```
Select 'HYYYYMMDD', 'EmailAddress_Header' union all
Select Customer#, EmailAddress from dbo.customertable union all
Select concat('T0000',cast((Select count(*) from dbo.customertable) as varchar)), 'EmailAddress_Footer'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this is a good way to go about it, but I will still have to do some manipulation in the final file. But I don't think there's really a way to avoid that manipulation since you must have the 2 column structure. I appreciate the help as this will at least save me some time.